# How to prevent withRouter causing rerendering PureComponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can invoke a link by `history.push("/path")`. To access `history`, I have to use `withRouter` which passes multiple props to the component. `match` passed by `withRouter` is different even if the path does not change. This causes `PureComponent` to rerender. Is there a way to work around this?

Example:

```
class HomeButton extends PureComponent {
  onClick = () => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    history.push("/");
  }

  render() {
    return <Button onClick={this.onClick}/>
  }
}

export default withRouter(HomeButton);
```

I used [shallowEqualExplain](https://github.com/OliverJAsh/shallow-equal-explain) to check which props causing the update.

Comment: what are you getting in match and what do you want it to be?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala I don't need `match` but I need `history`. `withRouter` give it to me anyways.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am running into the exact same issue.

Comment: @RyanPergent I have moved away from the class approach and use React hook instead.

Comment: @Joshua the component gets rerendered even if it's a function component with hooks instead of a class though. Did you stop using `withRouter` altogether or did you somehow solve the issue?

Comment: @RyanPergent I don'treally care about this now as I move to pre-render solution like Gatsby or Next.js. They provides much more performance than tinkering with this. If you really want to prevent this, you can create a wrapper and filter out unwanted properties before reaching you component.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use `Component` instead of `PureComponent` if you don't want to update `Button`.

> React.PureComponent’s shouldComponentUpdate() only shallowly compares the objects. If these contain complex data structures, it may produce false-negatives for deeper differences.

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

Comment: Yep, that's correct, PureComponent is not appropriate here, please use a component and make use of shouldComponentUpdate() to check for differences manually, that will help for sure.

Comment: This is one of the solutions but it is painful one. Especially when there is multiple components uses `withRouter` and all the other props work fine. Also, this need to write compare functions for all other props.

Comment: Is there a way, like some kind of decorator, that can filter away the `match` props?

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate

Comment: any solution with hooks?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. Using `shouldComponentUpdate` created worst issues plus more boilerplate code. Plus, the documentation argues that this should be avoided at all costs.

Instead, I used the `Link` component from `react-router-dom` package.

**CSS**

```
.HomeButton {
  text-decoration: unset;
  color: unset;
}
```

**JS**

```
function HomeButton() {
  return (
    <Link className='HomeButton' to="/"> 
      <Button />
    </Link>
  )
}

export default HomeButton;
```

Note: Your component isn't pure because of `withRouter`. If you remove `withRouter` than it is pure. Of course, then you would have to use `Link` because you won't have access to `history` at that point.